# Django FilteredSelectMultiple will not validate

Tags: python, django

I am trying to change my many to many script field to use FilteredSelectMultiple widget. It works up to validation where it says "Select a valid choice. 12 is not one of the available choices." and 12 is the right database id for that ResponseAction.

Form:

```
class ResponseConfigurationForm(ModelForm):
    scripts=forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=ResponseAction.objects.all(),widget=FilteredSelectMultiple("ResponseAction",False,attrs={'rows':'5'}))

class Meta:
    model = ResponseConfiguration
```

Script model:

```
scripts = models.ManyToManyField('ResponseAction')
```

I can't find the problem.

Comment: have you tried if 11 works, the widget values might start at zero

Comment: @ArgsKwargs all that is done by Django.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that memcached kept some tables in memory and therefor it failed.

Solution remove all tables of the app. Syncdb and restart memcached.